# Pick a specific element from a list and append it on to another list

Tags: python, list, loops, append

I have two list x and y

```
x = ['13', '77', '58', '792', '171']

y = []
```

I need all elements that start with '7' in x to be added to y

I have tried something along the lines of this:

```
i = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    if i[0] == '7':
        y.append(i[0])
        i += 1
```

Comment: `y.extend(e for e in x if e.startswith('7'))`

Comment: change `y.append(i[0])` to `y.append(i)`

Comment: and `i += 1` won't have an effect on your program, nor do you need a `i = 0` before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [16]: x = ['13', '77', '58', '792', '171']

In [17]: y = [i for i in x if i.startswith('7')]

In [18]: y
Out[18]: ['77', '792']
```

Answer (score 1):

I went for a more verbose solution that is correct and should be easy to read.

```
x = ['13', '77', '58', '792', '171']

y = []

for e in x:
    if e[0] == '7':
        y.append(e)
```

Comment: How would I remove the first character in a list of strings

I have:

    x = ['76776', '766', '71']

I am trying to return
    
    x = ['6776', '66', '1']

Comment: @dontworry123 try this `y.append(e[1:])` in place of `y.append(e)`

Answer (score 0):

Another concise way would be to use the handy filter() function, which takes a function that will return a "bool" (a lambda function, in this case.)

```
x = ['13', '77', '58', '792', '171']
y = list(filter(lambda item: item.startswith('7'), x))
```

(this doesn't append the elements to y, not sure if that's required.)
Not bulletproof, but works for your example.